# Shortest Path by rolling a dice

Tags: algorithm, dijkstra, shortest-path

I have a difficult problem to solve (at least that's how I see it). I have a **die** (faces 1 to 6) with different values (others than [1-6]), and a **board** (n-by-m). I have a starting position and a finish position. I can move from a square to another by rolling the die. By doing this I have to add the top face to the sum/cost.

Now I have to calculate how to get from the start position to the end position with a minimum
sum/cost. I have tried almost everything but I can't find the correct algorithm.

I tried Dijkstra but it's useless because in the right path there are some intermediate nodes
that I can reach with a better sum from another path (that proves to be incorrect in the end). How should I change my algorithm?

algorithm overview:
dijkstra : PriorityQueue
if(I can get to a node with a smaller sum)
,remove it from the queue,
I change its cost and its die position
,add it to queue.

This is the code :

```
public void updateSums() {

    PriorityQueue<Pair> q = new PriorityQueue<>(1, new PairComparator());

    Help h = new Help();

    q.add(new Pair(startLine, startColumn, sums[startLine][startColumn]));

    while (!q.isEmpty()) {

        Pair current = q.poll();

        ArrayList<Pair> neigh = h.getNeighbours(current, table, lines, columns);

        table[current.line][current.column].visit(); //table ->matrix with Nodes

        for (Pair a : neigh) {

            int alt = sums[current.line][current.column] + table[current.line][current.column].die.roll(a.direction);

            if (sums[a.line][a.column] > alt) {

                q.remove(new Pair(a.line, a.column, sums[a.line][a.column]));

                sums[a.line][a.column] = alt; //sums -> matrix with costs

                table[a.line][a.column].die.setDie(table[current.line][current.column].die, a.direction);

                q.add(new Pair(a.line, a.column, sums[a.line][a.column]));
            } 

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Dijkstra's Algorithm should work fine here, as should other graph exploration algorithms like [A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm). Can you post the implementation of Djikstra's Algorithm you tried, plus the code you used to drive it? The problem may lie in that code.

Comment: Related:  [A* Admissible Heuristic for die rolling on grid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16547724)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to also consider the position of the die in your Dijkstra states.

I.e. you cannot just have `sums[lines][column]`, you'll have to do something such as `sums[lines][column][die_config]`, where `die_config` is some way you create to convert the die position into an integer.

For example, if you have a die that looks like this initially:

> ^1 <4 v2 >9 f5 b7  (^ = top face, < = left... down, right, front and
>   back)

`int initial_die[6] = {1,4,2,9,5,7}`

You can convert it to an integer by simply considering the index of the face (from 0 to 5) that is pointing **up** and the one that is to the **left**. This means your die has less than 36 *(see bottom note)* possible rotation positions, which you can encode through something such as *(0-based)* `(up*6 + left)`. By this I mean each face would have a value from 0 through 5 that you decide, regardless of their cost-associated value, so following the example above we would encode the initially top face as being the index `0`, the left face as being the index `1`, and so on.

So the die with config value `30` means that `left = 30%6 (=0)` the face that was initially pointing up (initial_die[0]), is currently pointing to the left, and `up = (30 - left)/6 (=5)` the face that is currently pointing up, is the one that was initially pointing to the **back** of the die (initial_die[5]). **So this means the die currently has the cost 1 on its left face, and the cost 7 on its top face**, and you can derive the rest of the die's faces from this information, since you know the initial disposition. (Basically this tells us the die rolled once to its left, followed by once towards its front, in comparison to the initial state)

With this additional information, your Dijkstra will be able to find the correct answer you seek, by considering the cheapest cost that reaches the final node, as you could have multiple with different final die positions.

*Note: It doesn't actually have 36 possible positions, because some are impossible, for example two initially opposite sides won't be able to become adjacent on Up/Left. There are in fact only 24 valid positions, but the simple encoding I used above will actually use indexes up to ~34 depending on how you encode your die.*

Comment: Sorry for asking!Maybe i am wrong , but a keep my die's position in a Node and if i can change the cost in the cost matrix i update the die's position in that node,it's not so clever like yours but i think it does what it should.I keep all six faces and i have methods to set the die by another's  position and rolling direction.Sorry if i miss something obvious:(

Comment: @user2403558 no need to be sorry! The problem with your algorithm is, what happens if you reach the *same node* with *same cost* and different die positions? You end up ignoring the second path, because it tied in cost, but maybe it's dice was in a better position for the next move!

For example, pretend you reach the second-to-last node with sum 300, and if you roll your die to the last node, your sum becomes 306. Now, you find a second way that reaches this second-to-last node with sum 300 also, and you ignore it! BUT maybe the die was in a position that rolling it to last node would cost 4.

Comment: In fact, this also happens if you reach second-to-last node with sum 299 (and die movement will cost 6), and you ignore/overwrite the other path that had sum 300 but would only cost 4 to reach the last node, from the same previous node. So you end up with answer 305 instead of 304. (This **also** happens in intermediate nodes)

Comment: There are 24 possible orientations (6 possible numbers facing up, and four ways to rotate the die on the vertical axis).  You can encode it like that with no waste.